# JDK9 Packager: Create image without runtime

Tags: java, javafx, java-9, jlink, javapackager

When using the Java Packager in Java 8, one had the choice to *not* include a runtime in the resulting image (see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36907582/4014509)).

I'm trying to achieve the same (using the ant tasks [described over here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/javafx-ant-tasks.htm)). However I don't know how to not include the JVM in the resulting `.app` or `.exe` file.

```
<fx:deploy nativeBundles="image" ...>
    <fx:runtime anythingICanDoHere?>
    ...
</fx:deploy>
```

The reason why I am asking: I am creating my own runtime using the `jlink` utility and want to replace the default runtime bundled with the application. This works just fine, but as replace the default runtime anyway, it is an unnecessary step to include it in the first place.

Side note: The application is not yet JPMS compliant, so the entire JVM is included.

Answer (score 0):

The `javapackager` provided with JDK 9 and up uses `jlink` to generate the jre image:

> For self-contained applications, the Java Packager for JDK 9 packages 
>   applications with a JDK 9 runtime image generated by the jlink tool. To 
>   package a JDK 8 or JDK 7 JRE with your application, use the JDK 8 Java 
>   Packager.
>
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/javapackager.htm#JSWOR719

You can even pass arguments to `jlink` using `-BjlinkOptions=<options>`